# Make a call through com.sun.proxy instance

Tags: java, proxy, ejb, corba

I have a program which performs a lookup through what seems to be a Naming Service. The strange thing is that sometimes the lookup returns an IOR but other times it returns a com.sun.proxy instance (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0@573745ec for example, which seems to be an instance).

Precisely, the code looks like this:

```
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"some.context.factory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, host+":"+port);
        p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "some.package.prefixes"); 
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);
        String ejbName = "some/lookup/string";

        Object obj = ctx.lookup(ejbName);
```

Then `obj` will be the com.sun.proxy instance. How do I perform a call to some method in the EJB found?

Comment: What is an IOR? And have you inspected the type of class `Proxy0` to see if it extends the class you are wanting? You haven't posted enough information to give you a clear answer, but it sounds like you're just getting an auto-generated proxy that you can use just like the original class.

Comment: IOR stands for Interoperable Object Reference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperable_Object_Reference). It's a CORBA/RMI-IIOP identifier for a remote object.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the proxy to the type that it proxies and then call methods:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) obj;
foo.someMethod(...);
```

If you don't have the type, then you can use Java Reflection to ask the proxy for its methods like you would with any normal instance:

```
obj.getClass().getMethods();
```

See [the Proxy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).